# When is the reference count for a local variable in a python function decreased?

Tags: python, local-variables, reference-counting

I have the following function:

```
def myfn():
    big_obj = BigObj()
    result = consume(big_obj)
    return result
```

When is the reference count for the value of BigObj() increased / decreased:
Is it:

1. when `consume(big_obj)` is called (since big_obj is not referenced afterwards in myfn)
2. when the function returns
3. some point, I don't no yet

Would it make a difference to change the last line to:

```
return consume(big_obj)
```

Edit (clarification for comments):

- A local variable exists until the function returns
- the reference can be deleted with del obj

But what is with temporaries (e.g f1(f2())?

I checked references to temporaries with this code:

```
import sys
def f2(c):
    print("f2: References to c", sys.getrefcount(c))


def f0():
    print("f0")
    f2(object())

def f1():
    c = object()
    print("f1: References to c", sys.getrefcount(c))
    f2(c)

f0()
f1()
```

This prints:

```
f0
f2: References to c 3
f1: References to c 2
f2: References to c 4
```

It seems, that references to temporary variables are held. Not that getrefcount gives one more than you would expect because it holds a reference, too.

Comment: The variable `big_obj` still exists until the function returns, even if there are no more lines of code that will access it.  The only thing you could possibly do to affect its lifetime is `del big_obj`, but that's pointless to do if the function is about to return anyway.  (It might be very useful if further memory-intensive operations are going to be done in the function, but `big_obj` is no longer needed.)

Comment: Is there a possibility to call `consume(big_obj)`so that reference in `myfn` is deleted and a reference is hold inside `consume` fn. So basically something similar like a move operation in C++?

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: I hava a lazy SingleLinkedList. Roughly like this: `(value, next_fn)`The next item of the list is a function, which is called, when the next item is first accessed. Next item is replaced by the return value of next_fn, which is either another `(value, next_fn)` or `None`. So `big_obj` holds a reference to the head of the list and as long as big_obj is referenced, all generated items are hold in memory, too ...

Comment: try maybe just `consume(BigObj())`? anyway, this would all be counting on *implementation details* anyway, there is no language guarantee that an object will be reclaimed immediately when it's reference count reaches zero (although in CPython it is)

Comment: You are looking for implementation details.  Python gives you no guarantee of when the object is actually deleted.

Comment: `consume(BigObj())`did not work. I ran `gc.collect`on every iteration. It is not that import that the object is reclaimed immediately, but that it could be reclaimed. Otherwise the program would ultimately run out of memory

Comment: @FrankYellin ok. but is there an explicit way to enforce this, so that I do not have to rely on implementation details?

Comment: Is `gc.collect` relevant here? That only controls the auxilliary garabage collector that handles reference cycles.

Comment: " It is not that import that the object is reclaimed immediately, but that it could be reclaimed. Otherwise the program would ultimately run out of memory " Not sure I understand, then it seems to me it shouldn't matter if `big_obj` is referenced in `myfn` after `consume` terminates, since it is gone by the time the function returns

Comment: If in 'consume' there would be processed a billion items or so, then it would matter. With 'gc.collect' I checked that memory consumption in increasing. I  also inserted an intermediate step, where I created a weakref and in consume I checked the weakref. The result is the same. The reference still exists.

Comment: My point is simply that `gc.collect` is *not relevant here*, it is a red herring. It would never affect anything, unless you've created a reference cycle, have you?

Comment: You understand that a reference count can increase or decrease multiple times, right? And that decreasing a reference count *does not* cause garbage collection *unless* it falls to zero?

Comment: I tried to answer the question you actually asked, but I strongly suspect it's not the question you actually *have*. You should start over, showing enough code to reproduce an actual problem, and explain what that problem is. It should be clear when someone else runs the code that something happens that is different from what is supposed to happen (for example, progressively increasing memory usage, or a `MemoryError` exception). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: It seems that references to temporaries from functions are hold until the end of the an enclosing function, too. I edited my question and added a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Most information is from the comments. So credit for every one who participated in the discussion.

When an object is deleted is an implementation detail in general.
I will refer to CPython, which is based on reference counting. I ran the code examples with CPython 3.10.0.

- An object is deleted, when the reference count hits zero.
- Returning from a function deletes all local references.
- Assigning a name to a new value decreases the reference count of the old value
- passing a local increases the reference count. The reference is in on the stack(frame)
- Returning from a function removes the reference from the stack

The last point is even valid for temporary references like `f(g())`. The last reference to g() is deleted, when f returns (assuming that g does not save a reference somewhere)[see here](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Epconrad/cs8/topics.beta/theStack/03/)

So for the example from the question:

```
def myfn():
    big_obj = BigObj() # reference 1                     
    result = consume(big_obj) # reference 2 on the stack frame for  
                              # consume. Not yet counting any 
                              # reference inside of consume
                              # after consume returns: The stack frame 
                              # and reference 2 are deleted. Reference  
                              # 1 remains
    return result             # myfn returns reference 1 is deleted. 
                              # BigObj is deleted
def consume(big_obj):
    pass # consume is holding reference 3
```

If we would change this to:

```
def myfn():
    return consume(BigObj()) # reference is still saved on the stack 
                             # frame and will be only deleted after  
                             # consume returns
def consume(big_obj):
    pass # consume is holding reference 2
```

**How can I check reliably, if an object was deleted?**

You cannot rely on gc.get_objects(). gc is used to detect and recycle reference cycles. Not every reference is tracked by the gc.
You can create a weak reference and check if the reference is still valid.

```
class BigObj:
    pass

import weakref
ref = None

def make_ref(obj):
    global ref
    ref = weakref.ref(obj)
    return obj

def myfn():
    return consume(make_ref(BigObj()))

def consume(obj):
    obj = None # remove to see impact on ref count
    print(sys.getrefcount(ref()))
    print(ref()) # There is still a valid reference. It is the one from consume stack frame
```

myfn()

**How to pass a reference to a function and remove all references in the calling function?**

You can box the reference, pass to the function and clear the boxed reference from inside the function:

```
class Ref:
    def __init__(ref):
        self.ref = ref
    def clear():
        self.ref = None

def f1(ref):
    r = ref.ref
    ref.clear()

def f2():
    f1(Ref(object())
```

Comment: `# reference is still saved on the stack ` ah yes, of course

Comment: That gave me headache. I was not aware of this. I was trusting that like move semantics or copy elision would happen for temporaries. Do you know why an additional reference is saved on the stack? Is it to prevent dropping the reference count to zero before entering the function? I don't know if that makes sense. The reference is saved in the locals dict, too.

Answer (score 2):

> When is the reference count for big_obj decreased

`big_obj` **does not have** a reference count. Variables don't have reference counts. *Values* do.

```
big_obj = BigObj()
```

This line of code creates an instance of the `BigObj` class. The reference count for that instance may increase or decrease multiple times, depending on the implementation details of that creation process (which is not necessarily written in Python). Notably, though, the *assignment to the name `big_obj`* increases the reference count.

> when the function returns

*At this point*, the name `big_obj` ceases to exist - the name does *not* disappear simply because it won't be used again. (That's really hard to detect in the general case, and there isn't a particular benefit to it normally). If you must *cause* a name to cease to exist at a specific point in the operation (for example, because you *know* that is the last reference and want to trigger garbage collection; or perhaps because you are doing something tricky with `__weakref__`) then that is what the `del` statement is for.

Because a name for the object ceases to exist, its reference count decreases. *If and when that count reaches zero*, the object is garbage collected. It may have any number of references stored in other places, for a wide variety of reasons. (For example, there could be a bug in C code that implements the class; or the class might deliberately maintain its own list of every instance ever created.)

---

Note that all of the above pertains specifically to the reference implementation. In other implementations, things will differ. There might be some other trigger for garbage collection to happen. There *might not be reference counting at all* (as with Jython).

From the comments, it seems like what you are worried about is the potential for a memory leak. The code that you show cannot *cause* a memory leak - but neither can it fix a memory leak caused elsewhere. In Python, as in garbage-collected languages in general, memory leaks happen because objects hold on to references to each other *that aren't needed*. But there is no concept of "ownership" or "transfer" of references normally - all you need to do is *not* do things like "maintain a list of every instance ever created" without a) a good reason and b) a way to take instances out of that list when you want to forget about them.

A *local variable*, though, *by definition*, cannot extend the lifetime of an object beyond the local scope.

Comment: I am aware that big_obj has no reference count, but the value of BigObj() has. I was sloppy about that in the question. You are right, I was worried about a memory leak caused by a reference that prevents the reference count from dropping to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Variables have function scope in Python, so they aren't removed until the function returns. As far as I can tell, you can't destroy a reference to a local variable in a function from outside that function. I added some `gc` calls in the example code to test this.

```py
import gc
class BigObj:
    pass
def consume(obj):
    del obj  # only deletes the local reference to obj, but another one still exists in the calling function

def myfn():
    big_obj = BigObj()
    big_obj_id = id(big_obj)  # in CPython, this is the memory address of the object
    consume(big_obj)
    print(any(id(obj) == big_obj_id for obj in gc.get_objects()))
    return big_obj_id

>>> big_obj_id = myfn()
True
>>> gc.collect()  # I'm not sure where the reference cycle is, but I needed to run this to clean out the big object from the gc's list of objects in my shell
>>> print(any(id(obj) == big_obj_id for obj in gc.get_objects()))
False
```

Since `True` was printed, the big object still existed after we forced garbage collection to occur even though there were no references to that variable after that point in the function. Forcing garbage collection after the function returns rightfully determines that the reference count to the big object is 0, so it cleans that object up. NOTE: As the comments below point out, ids for deleted objects may be reused so checking for equal ids may result in false positives. However, I'm confident that the conclusion is still correct.

One thing you can do to reclaim that memory earlier is to make the big object global, which could allow you to delete it from within the called function.

```py
def consume():
    # do whatever you need to do with the big object
    big_obj_id = id(big_obj)
    del globals()["big_obj"]
    print(any(id(obj) == big_obj_id for obj in gc.get_objects()))
    # do anything else you need to do without the big object

def myfn():
    globals()["big_obj"] = BigObj()
    result = consume()
    return result

>>> myfn()
False
```

This sort of pattern is pretty weird and likely very hard to maintain though, so I would advise against using this. If you only need to delete the big object right after `consume()` is called, you could do something like this in order to free up the memory used by the big object as soon as possible.

```py
big_obj = BigObj()
consume(big_obj)
del big_obj
```

Another strategy you might try is deleting the references within the big object that's passed in from the `consume()` function with `del big_obj.x` for some attribute `x`.

Comment: "I added some gc calls in the example code to test this." **`gc.collect` is not relevant here**. Please understand `gc` doesn't really affect the objects here

Comment: Note, if you do `x = object(); big_id = id(x); any(id(item) == big_id for item in gc.get_objects())` you will get `False`, and using `id(x) = big_id` is fraught with problems to begin with, because it could give you false positives since ID's are only guaranteed to be unique for the *lifetime of the object*, id's can and frequently are re-used

Comment: Although, I think for user-defined objects, `any( ....)` will be True. Although again, this is an implementation detail.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. `id(x) == big_id` cannot return false negatives. Getting a `False` result implies the object is truly deleted, which is what the output shows.

Comment: If `gc.collect()` deletes the object as the OP wants, how does that make it irrelevant?

Comment: No, `gc.collect()` **does not**. CPython's main garbage collection strategy is *reference counting*. Objects are reclaimed *immediately* when their reference counts get to zero. `gc.collect()` runs the *auxilliary garbage collector*, which handles reference cycles. Most objects will never be handled by `gc.collect`, and it's usually not relevant unless you know you have a reference cycle and a memory leak related to a reference cycle

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok I understand your point now. If I remove the calls to `gc.collect()`, do you have any issues with the rest of my answer?

Comment: Somewhat, again, the idea that `print(any(id(obj) == big_obj_id for obj in gc.get_objects()))` is a valid way to check if an object has been deleted, even if it returns false. Some objects arent' tracked by `gc` at all, although currently I think it does track all user-defined objects. I'm trying to find an answer to that. EDIT: it may "just work" for now, but I would definitely add some caveats.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga an alternative way to think about this is, do you have any suggestions for better tests to check whether an object is deleted?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I checked the gc.get_objects() approach. I can confirm that it does not track all references (tested with CPython 3.10.0)

Comment: @rchome I think a reliable test is to create a global weak reference and check if that weak reference is still valid.